# Full-height responsive div obstructed by h3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple of divs sat side by side that need the button to be on the bottom.
I need the button to sit on the bottom of the `.col-sm-4` container, without the `h3` tag pushing it further out. Does anyone have a hack or some kind of solution?

The h3 tag size needs to be responsive as its text may change. I've got it to a point where the boxes are pushed out of the container, but now I'm stuck.

**____________________Better explanation_______________**

My `h3` tag is pushing my `.col-sm-4` outside of the container. I need the button to be at the bottom of the div.

In this js.fiddle, I have provided two divs. The first one is where I want the button, but I need the `h3` tag to look like div 2. I can't seem to achieve the second div without the button being pushed out of the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/19obrm0q/1/

- edit - h4 -> h3.

Comment: There is no h4 tag in your html. And, just a fair warning, this question is confusing and the SO gods may punish you. Try providing a visual of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry! that's what I meant.

I was hoping the visual on jsfiddle might explain it better. One sec.

Comment: @Jbird does that clear things up a little better?
I realized the jsfiddle didn't update either. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/19obrm0q/5/

After much fiddling about: BEFORE:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 bg-white pad-sm-top text-center full-height full-width">
        <h3 class="clear-margin text-banner-activity fix text-center"> SOME TEXT</h3>
        <p class="clear-margin">SOME TEXT</p>
        <div class="center-bottom">
          <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-activity-light btn-md"> Learn more &gt; </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and AFTER:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 no-pad bg-white">
   <h3 class="clear-margin text-banner-activity text-center">heading</h3>
      <div class="col-sm-12 pad-sm-top pad-xlg-bot text-center">
        inner
      </div>
      <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-activity-light btn-md center-bottom">
        button
      </a>
    </div>
```

I moved the divs around and got rid of the div that was nesting the button, and now it works, the button sits on the bottom no matter the size of the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an element with nonzero height in the same container as a `full-height` div and expect both to fit in 100% of the parent's height. That's what `height: 100%` means.

I've tried again, this time keeping the `h3` outside the `col-sm-12` as required. To make this work I've moved the `full-height` class up a level to the `col-sm-4`. I also had to move the `center-bottom` element outside the `col-sm-12`. This is because now that the `col-sm-4` is the element with defined height, it should also be the element which defines the position context for the `absolute` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/19obrm0q/7/

Comment: Thanks! I think we managed to figure out the same thing, I posted a comment earlier yesterday to show.

Comment: aha, I didn't notice that was your answer. Please click the check mark to accept an answer so others know your problem is solved. Happy to help!

Comment: thanks man! Yeah, I have a 2 day delay before I can check my own answers out. It's checked now for future viewers of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

First, your markup was a little different between the two columns: one had the `h3` inside the parent div and the other had it before/outside, which was contributing to making them look different.

But my suggested solution is to pad the bottom of the parent so that there's sure to be room for the absolute positioned button.

Have a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/19obrm0q/3/

Comment: That, functionally, provides what I need to do. But visually, I am needing my header to be full-width (like my second `col-sm-4`)

I had to put the `h3` outside of that to show the full-width that I needed.